# Spring using windows user instead of given username 'root' to hit the mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

Getting the error

> "Access denied for user 'DEll'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

In the spring xml file I have given the user as 'root' not dell. I have tried everything. I believe there will be simple solution for this.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}"></property>
<property name="url" value="${url}"></property>
<property name="username" value="${username}"></property>
<property name="password" value="${password}"></property>
</bean>
```

The property file is

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
username=root
password=12345
```

Comment: Maybe duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41645309/3728901

Comment: No . I want to clarify that my problem is that spring is using windows 'Dell' user to hit the mysql database instead of the given mysql user in the configuration file which is 'root.

Comment: It doesn't happen anymore `Windows username to DB username?`

Comment: are you sure user has access to database ?

Comment: the DB username is given in the spring configuration file spring should use the username given in the spring xml.

Comment: yes I am very sure. Infact the error message says it clearly says that its picking windows user.

Comment: @AdivyaYadav I didn't noticed that, there is different user

Comment: Have you an another data source config? I guest you have an another configuration, use Spring LDAP like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14174141/3728901

Comment: @AdivyaYadav it is better to debug your code, if it is somewhere hardcoded. By changing some of the property value

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've discovered `USERNAME` is already a reserved system environment variable. Maybe because you're on windows, the case insensitity is finding the lowercase version

Try changing your property and reference to:

`user=root` and `<property name="username" value="${user}"></property>`